# How to increase the thickness of a `Slider` control

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a slider control in my grid:

```
<Slider x:Name="MainSlider"
        Margin="659,145,417,146"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Orientation="Vertical"
        SmallChange="1"
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.0799999982118607,0.5"/>
```

I want it to be wider though, so that the whole bar is stretched out.

I've gone through the properties and `Width` doesn't actually change the thickness of the slider itself, just the frame.

How can I make the actual `Slider` thicker?

Comment: You will probably need to define your own style. You can copy the default style (using Expression Blend for example) and tweak the individual component values.

Comment: @ChrisF Wow, I don't know how I missed the `Edit Style` option before. Noobed out, but thanks. If you post an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will probably need to define your own style. You can copy the default style (using Expression Blend for example) and tweak the individual component values.

Use the "Edit Style" option to take a copy of the template and then work on that.

There's more information on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc295021%28v=expression.40%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can customize the style template of Slider as per your requirement:

http://codingsense.wordpress.com/2010/02/01/customize-a-slider-in-wpf-step-by-step-tutorial/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms753256%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you make a template from a copy of the slider template:

Right-Click Slider->"Edit Template" -> "Edit a Copy"

Then you can change the TrackBackground and PART_SelectionRange WIDTH to whatever you want. They were "4.0" by default for my case:

```
<Border x:Name="TrackBackground"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Width="XX.X"
        Margin="0,5"
        HorizontalAlignment="center"
        Background="{StaticResource HorizontalSliderTrackNormalBackground}"
        BorderBrush="{StaticResource VerticalSliderTrackNormalBorder}"
        BorderThickness="1"
        CornerRadius="1">
    <Canvas Margin="-1,-6">
        <Rectangle x:Name="PART_SelectionRange"
                   Width="XX.X"
                   Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"
                   Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlDarkDarkBrushKey}}"
                   StrokeThickness="1.0"
                   Visibility="Hidden" />
    </Canvas>
</Border>
```